# Firebase+GTM SDK - passing strings longer than 100 characters

Tags: google-tag-manager, firebase-analytics

I am moving from GTM SDK to Firebase+GTM SDK (v5) library in my mobile apps. I am only interested in data in Google Analytics and don't really care about what is being registered inside Firebase Analytics.

It all works as expected but when I am passing longer than 100 characters strings to GTM, Firebase Analytics is throwing such warning:

> [Firebase/Analytics][I-ACS013000] Event parameter value is too long.
>   The maximum supported length is 100

This is consistent with the documentation.

While it still works, what bothers me if with a new Firebase SDK release will it become more strict and event values longer than 100 chars will be lost

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Did a little of experimenting and as of today it does work: passing strings longer than 100 characters to Firebase+GTM SDK, using them in GTM and seeing long values in GA.

However, since this is an unofficially supported there is no way of saying if a newer version of the Firebase+GTM SDK library would still allow that.
I completely agree with you here - 100 chars limit is a very frustrating limitation for the Google Analytics world.